# Running Flutter App on to the Server without having access to internet

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Flutter Technology and running projects on Server but whenever i start running Flutter web Applications on to the Server, it doesn't load the Application and stucked there and giving a white screen output.

Is there any Solution how to execute flutter web App on to the Server without accessing internet.

Comment: It also happens localy If i start an application with flame/forge2d and no Internet connection.